# Content Delivery server setup | HTTP UPLOAD server role , tridion object cache Queries

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, 2011-sp1

Currently I'm in the process of setting up Content Distribution in **SDL  Tridion 2011 SP1**. We are using **HTTPS** as the transport protocol.

With reference to the steps [**`here`**](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-EE0D88D8-A1C2-4BB6-B5F1-C86728D0D0B6.xml&docid=GUID-EE0D88D8-A1C2-4BB6-B5F1-C86728D0D0B6&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EE0D88D8-A1C2-4BB6-B5F1-C86728D0D0B6), Steps 1 and 5 is confusing.

*So far what has been done as per my understanding ( and misunderstanding as well ) is :*
 
1.) Created/Installed the HTTP UPLOAD server role as IIS .Net Website
2.) Placed the JAR files inside bin\lib\ and Configuration files inside bin\Config\ folder as per the [**`Universal installation procedure`**](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-BF734F03-BA0E-44F1-841A-19D1AC8F43C4.xml&docid=GUID-BF734F03-BA0E-44F1-841A-19D1AC8F43C4&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-BF734F03-BA0E-44F1-841A-19D1AC8F43C4) for Server roles
3.) Placed `HttpUpload.aspx` into this HTTP UPLOAD Server Role .Net website
4.) place the relevant DLLs in bin folder.
5.) Appropriate entries made in cd_deployer_conf, cd_storage_conf

Now the question is:

---

**May be this is my Misunderstood part**

*Do  each of the individual Asp.Net websites ( Which are actual development websites for different projects/Brands), should also contain the JAR Files, cd_deployer_conf, cd_storage_conf files in there respective bin\lib\ , bin\config\ folders* ?

*Why the development websites [ in addition to HTTP UPLOAD ] also need to contain separate copies of Jar files and Config files?*

---

*Do the JAR / Configuration files of HTTP UPLOAD website takes complete care of receiving and distributing the content to Content Data Store / File System ?? OR whether these JAR/Configuration files needs to be deployed on each of these individual development websites too ??*

Also, *the Content Deployer role and HTTP UPLOAD server role seems the same here. Are they really different, because to configure content deployer, we actually install HTTP UPLOAD and then configure its cd_deployer_conf file as outlined [**`here`**](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-15325840-355A-49EE-96A3-7806594CF082.xml&docid=GUID-15325840-355A-49EE-96A3-7806594CF082&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-15325840-355A-49EE-96A3-7806594CF082)*

---

*Lastly, when enabling the **Tridion Caching** option as : `<ObjectCache Enabled="true">` in cd_storage_conf , is this Tridion Object Cache applicable only for Content Data Store items ? [**`SdlTridionWorld`**](https://sdltridionworld.com/articles/whatisthesdltridionobjectcache.aspx) mentions only Content Data Store. 

OR **is the caching applicable equally for FileSystem** ? (Means a truly static `.aspx` page just published from CME will be cached too ? )  If Yes, is it safe to assume the cache will be invalidated as per the  Least Recently Used caching policy ??*

Comment: In a rush: maybe this helps? http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/07/manually-configuring-tridion-2011-net.html

Comment: Not really in a rush :) . This article of yours is great!!. So, I concluded that I don't need to deploy JAR and those configs (cd_deployer_conf, cd_storage_conf ) to my development websites .

Comment: I was in a rush, that's why I only posted the link :)

Answer (score 2):

**For #1:** For .Net MVC based implementations, the Jar files are needed if you want to enable in context editing for your website (which uses Tridion APIs), else you do not need the Jars as part of your actual website. For oData service(from Tridion) setup  you will need these jars. Responsibility of oData is to serve content to the consumers (in this case the website) and the website does not need the jars
**For # 2:** The distribution of content is done via the deployer module and you do not need the JARs on your consumer. The deployer will deploy content to the appropriate target based on the settings in the configuration files. HTTPUpload and deployer module are the same 
**For #3:** It depends upon what is your deployment architecture. If you use oData and have this setting for cache as "true" on oData, then deployer will communicate with oData using cache channel service to clear cache on publish. And consumers who call oData will get the latest content on every publish (provided there is no local caching on consumer side which is the actual website).

Comment: Thank Vipin for this Insight . I'm still in process of implementing and checking these.... Will comment further